# DIMDIM Localization

Tags: tomcat

I try to change the files in
/usr/local/dimdim/ConferenceServer/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/webapps/dimdim/data/language
to Arabic but still characters not displayed well  how i cant change the language in dimdim to Arabic

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based of the customization PDF, page 6, language addition is an Enterprise feature. If you are using an open source version, you may not be able to use the additional xx_XX.properties.
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=11&ved=0CEIQFjAK&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhowtomakemoneywithwebinars.com%2Fdocuments%2FDimdim_Customization_Guide.pdf&ei=LKNfS6HfB4Hm7APFjIDCDA&usg=AFQjCNEDpFOr3NMejyrcKSNRR-mC_XWvEA&sig2=eWTSijJei1NXJ3OF1MYFWw